# How to set a callback to a fancybox2 after it was rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I want to set a callback function to a fancybox 2 after the fancybox was rendered.. Is this possible?

I'm trying:

```
//myRenderedPopup.jsp
parent.$.fancybox.afterClose = function(){
    console.log("test");
}
```

But it isn't working..

Answer (score 2):

You can hook into the `afterShow` Callback. There are other hooks available in the [Fancybox Documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs).

> afterShow :    Called after open animations has ended